# Worst Fit Algorithm using an Array C++

Tags: c++, algorithm

I've created a code which is supposed to demonstrate the Worst Fit Algorithm using an array of size 256 (memory[256]), the code displays a map showing how the memory is being stored, the code allows the user to delete a memory location too , I want to have another array of any other size but larger than the first array , let's say memory2[456] , according to the Worst Fit Algorithm the elements should be added to the bigger memory first until it becomes smaller than the other and so on , the problem is that I can't think of a way of how to use the second array that I want to add to my code and add the elements to it first and then switch to the other array when the larger array becomes smaller than the other , could someone please help me !!

P.S I can't use a node,vector,linked list or any other thing it has to be an array

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int PutInMemory(int memory[], int size)
{
    
    if (size < 1)
        cout << "Error!" << endl;
    int firstSize = 0;
    int j;
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        if (memory[i] < 0 && abs(memory[i]) >= size)
        {
            j = i;
            firstSize += abs(memory[j]);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (firstSize < size)
    {
        cout << "Out of Memory";
        return 0;
    }
    if (j + size <= 256)
    {
        memory[j] = size;
        for (int i = j + 1; i < j + size; i++)
            memory[i] = 0;
        int i = j + size;
        int count = 0;
        while (memory[i] <= -1 && i < 256)
        {
            count++;
            i++;
        }
        if (count != 0)
        {
            memory[i - 1] = -count;
            memory[j + size] = -count;
        }
        return j;
        
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Out of memory";
    }
    
}

void DelSeg(int memory[], int n)
{
    int count = memory[n];
    int prev = 0;
    int next = count - 1;
    int i = n + 1;
    int pos = n;
    if (memory[n - 1] < -1 && n != 0)
    {
        i += memory[n - 1];
        prev = -memory[n - 1];
        count -= memory[n - 1];
        pos = i;
    }
    while (true)
    {
        for (i; i < pos + count - 1; i++)
        {
            memory[i] = -1;
        }
        if (memory[i + 1] < -1)
        {
            count += -memory[i + 1] + 1;
            next = -memory[i + 1];
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    
    memory[n - prev] = 0 - count;
    memory[n + next] = 0 - count;
}

void checkMemory(int memory[])
{
    int countFreeSeg = 0;
    int countFullSeg = 0;
    int countFullMem = 0;
    int countFreeMem = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        if (memory[i] < 0)
        {
            if (memory[i] < 0)
                cout << "Beginning of the adress:" << i << ", ";
            int count = 0;
            while (memory[i] < 0 && i < 256)
            {
                count++;
                i++;
            }
            countFreeSeg++;
            cout << "Size = " << count << endl;
            countFreeMem += count;
            i--;
        }
    }
    cout << "Number of free processes = " << countFreeSeg << endl << endl;
    cout << "Number of free memory = " << countFreeMem << endl << endl;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        if (memory[i] > 0)
        {
            cout << "Beginning adress: " << i << ", size - " << memory[i]
                    << endl;
            countFullMem += memory[i];
            i += memory[i] - 1;
            countFullSeg++;
        }
    }
    cout << "Number of occupied processes = " << countFullSeg << endl;
    cout << "Number of occupied memory = " << countFullMem << endl;
}

void print(int memory[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        cout << memory[i] << " ";
    }
}

int main()
{
    int memory[256];
    memory[0] = -256;
    for (int i = 1; i < 256; i++)
    {
        memory[i] = -1;
    }
    
    while (true)
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "1.Allocate Memory \n2.Free memory segment\n3.Get information about the memory\n4.Exit" << endl;
        int choice;
        cin >> choice;
        int m = 0;
        
        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
                system("cls");
                cout << "Enter the amount of memory to be entered:" << endl;
                cin >> m;
                cout << PutInMemory(memory, m) << endl;
                break;
            case 2:
                system("cls");
                cout << "Enter the starting address of the memory location:"
                        << endl;
                cin >> m;
                DelSeg(memory, m);
                break;
            case 3:
                checkMemory(memory);
                print(memory);
                break;
            case 4:
                system("cls");
                exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Incorrect entry" << endl;
                break;
        }
        system("pause");
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: Rather than printing "Out of memory" in `PutInMemory `'s final `else` and continuing as if nothing happened, make something happen like throwing an exception or signaling the failure to the program. At the very least, the program needs to return something in this case or deal with the mysteries of Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Unrelated: In this loop, `while (memory[i] <= -1 && i < 256)`, you should ensure `i<256` *before* you dereference the element in the array.  Like this: `while (i < 256 && memory[i] <= -1)`

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69215348/1458097

Comment: @phord oh ok I got it , do you know to answer the question I have asked ? I've been trying to do it for like 4 days , I can't think of a way to dot , could you at least instruct me on how to do it ?

Comment: @MohammedHamdoon Your question doesn't really make sense. You are simulating memory allocations in a heap called `memory`.  Then you introduce a new, larger heap called `memory2` and you want to insert items into this heap until it becomes "smaller", and then move to the smaller heap.  But this isn't how worstFit works (it doesn't use multiple heaps), and the new larger heap never gets "smaller".  Instead it just runs out of room for new allocations eventually.

Comment: @phord hmmm , then how can I Implement my code without introducing a new heap (memory2) for it to work according to the Worst Fit Algorithm ??

Comment: @MohammedHamdoon I replied in your other post with a specific code suggestion for how to implement worstFit. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69215348/worst-fit-algorithm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Worst fit algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69215348/worst-fit-algorithm)